# How to insert new line in middle of text file in java

Tags: file, merge

I want to insert the data at some positions in the text file without actually overwriting on the existing data

Answer (score 0):

If the text file is not too large then you could read it into an ArrayList and then manipulate certain positions where you want add/edit something and then write over the file with the contents from your ArrayList.

Reading text into ArrayList:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt"));
ArrayList<String> fileLines = new ArrayList<String>();
while (scanner.hasNext()){
    fileLines .add(scanner.next());
}
s.close();
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention it yeah my file size is big so dont want to read it

Answer (score 0):

You could do some sort of variation of copying the file(https://github.com/kentcdodds/Java-Helper/blob/master/src/com/kentcdodds/javahelper/helpers/IOHelper.java#L127) where you identify a random spot before-hand and write it in the output stream before the rest of that chunk. Here's some code below:

```
public static void saveInputStream(InputStream inputStream, File outputFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  int size = 4096;
  try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      out.write(buffer, 0, length);
      //Have length = the length of the random string and buffer = new byte[size of string]
      //and call out.write(buffer, 0, length) here once in a random spot.
      //Don't forget to reset the buffer = new byte[size] again before the next iteration.
    }
    inputStream.close();
  }
```

}
Call the above code like this:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("Your source file.whatever"));
saveInputStream(inputStream, new File("Your output file.whatever"));
```